# Неизвестный атрибут "no_init_all " и не удается открыть файл mfc140ud.lib

Tags: c++, ооп, классы, mfc

такие вот ошибки **Неизвестный атрибут "no_init_all " и  не удается открыть файл mfc140ud.lib** ,что только не пробовала делать,но они никуда не пропадают.

Заголовочный файл Header.h

```
#pragma once
#include "pch.h"
#include<iostream>
#include "atlcoll.h"
using namespace std;

class Absrt :public CObject
{
public:
    double Ipar;
    Absrt(double p)// конструктор с параметром
    {
        Ipar = p;
    }
    Absrt()// конструктор по умолчанию
    {
        Ipar = 0;
    }
    virtual void print() = 0;

};

class Deriv1 : public Absrt
{
public:
    double IDpar;
    Deriv1(double p)
    {
        IDpar = p;
    }
    Deriv1()
    {
        IDpar = 0;
    }
    void print() override
    {
        cout << "Вызов класса Deriv1 " << endl;
    }
};

class Deriv2 : public Deriv1
{
public:
    double IDpar;
    Deriv2(double p)
    {
        IDpar = p;
    }
    Deriv2()
    {
        IDpar = 0;
    }
    void print() override
    {
        cout << "Вызов класса Deriv2 " << endl;
    }
};

class Deriv3 : public Deriv1
{
public:
    double IDpar;
    Deriv3(double p)
    {
        IDpar = p;
    }
    Deriv3()
    {
        IDpar = 0;
    }
    void print() override
    {
        cout << "Вызов класса Deriv3 " << endl;
    }
};
```

Файл с функцией main()
На саму функцию main() внимания не обращайте

```
#include<iostream>
#include "framework.h"
#include "Project13.h"
#include "pch.h"
#include "Header.h"
#include "atlcoll.h"


//#ifdef _DEBUG
//#define new DEBUG_NEW
//#endif
using namespace std;

int main()
{
        //Absrt *a;
        Deriv1 e;
        e.print();
        return 0;

}
```

Comment: установлен ли у вас компонент Microsoft Foundation Classes for C++ в студии?

Comment: Да,я специально установила компонент MFC для x86 или x64 с устранение рисков Spectre

Comment: При создании проекта вы создавали c++ console application? по умолчанию этот шаблон создаёт "голую" консоль с минимумом зависимостей, скорее всего вам надо вручную указать пути к заголовочным файлам и библиотекам для корректной линковки. Или попробуйте создать mfc (или atl) проект из шаблона, там все необходимые пути будут уже прописаны.

Comment: Да, консольное,спасибо большое за помощь,я установила ещё один компонент  MFC для x86 или x64 вот такой,и эти ошибки пропали,но если опять появятся,то создам проект из шаблона по вашему совету.